# How to source a file in supervisor config?

Tags: supervisord

I want to source a file before running a command, but this doesn't worker.

```
[program:someprogram]
command=source /opt/pyenv.someenv/bin/activate && python scripts/some.py
directory=/root/p/somedir
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
```

After I `reread`, `update`, `status`, It says

```
supervisor> reread
someprogram: changed
supervisor> update
someprogram: stopped
someprogram: updated process group
supervisor> status
someprogram              FATAL      can't find command 'source'
```

And I tried

```
command=. /opt/pyenv.someenv/bin/activate && python scripts/some.py
```

It said

```
someprogram              FATAL      command at '/usr/local/sbin/.' is a directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try the calling the specific environment's python alias, I know this is how Passenger uses the correct virtual environment when executing Django at least.

`/opt/pyenv.someenv/bin/python /root/p/somedir/scripts/some.py`

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 1):

`source` is a bash builtin. You'll therefore want a bash shell. Something like:

```
[program:someprogram]
command=/bin/bash -c "source /opt/pyenv.someenv/bin/activate && python 
scripts/some.py"
```